# instagram login via php

Tags: php, instagram

as the Instagram changes the policy to fetch third-party user's images I need a help to create an Instagram login functionality which is built in php.

I created a client in an Instagram developer. and I know how to use the client's secret key and client id. and I also tested with some code which can do login functionality but whenever I try to login with my another Instagram account then it says "the account is not a sandbox user.".

are there any complete guidelines expect Instagram developer's guideline which shows an example of how to do the login functionality of third-party user.?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many libraries that will help with this, and save you time maintaining custom written code that could be eliminated by using something else that is established and working, for instance this one:

https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Specifically, this portion: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API#available-methods

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. i already told in question that i already tried code. but when I try to login with my another Instagram account then it says "the account is not a sandbox user.".

Comment: It's most likely the case that your account is in sandbox mode.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

"To get out of Sandbox mode, you need to submit your app for review. If your app falls into the approved use cases and gets approved, it will automatically go live. At this point any Instagram user will be able to authorize your app, but you will have access only to the permissions that you were granted during the review. If you need access to more permissions, you can submit for review again and you will not lose access to the permissions that you have already been granted."

Comment: Yes how to get out of the sandbox mode?

Comment: Please provide me link

Comment: and i think it is only for mobile application? or it is also use in website too?