# Login with Instagram

Tags: php, facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to implement Instagram login to my website using PHP and looking on the web I found out that I should get an access token a implement a lot of code to run it...

But [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) website says that it is not a login system, and I should use [Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)...

So how can I implement an **instagram** login?

Can it be done on [Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) website or should I use access tokens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [instagram login via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362106/instagram-login-via-php)

Comment: @AksenP pretty sure that is outdated by now; Facebook has retired the old Instagram APIs.

Comment: @AksenP it is outdated `Please note that this library doesn't yet support their new updates.`

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I implement an instagram login?

You can’t. That is not possible any more.

Facebook has removed the old Instagram APIs, and integrated this with their Graph API.

You *have to* use Facebook Login.

Comment: But I see some mobile applications or even websites which implement an instagram login... How?

Comment: Probably older implementations, that are still able to use these deprecated APIs. (The way these things usually work, is that existing apps get a certain amount of time to change their implementation, but new apps won’t be able to use the deprecated APIs any more.)

Comment: And what are access tokens for?

Comment: Access tokens are needed to make any advanced API calls.

Comment: @CBros thank you... But using facebook login can I get Instagram data? My website should work using Instagram profile names

Comment: I've already read lots off documentation, but each one links you to another one and that's overhelming trying to understand all that stuff... For a beginner it isn't easy managing these APIs without help! How can I get some users' access token using a login form? It isn't explained anywhere

Comment: Well you can’t really expect the API and its documentation for a network with over a billion users, to be geared towards enthusiastic beginner’s needs that much … But https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started outlines pretty much all the necessary steps.

Comment: Those websites that still work for "Login with Instagram" will likely no longer work at the end of March 2020 which is when Instagram says they will discontinue the legacy APIs.

Comment: @DavidBrossard so starting from March 2020 it won't be possible to create an Instagram Login?

Comment: I understood, but I have another problem with using facebook-login for instagram. could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369157/how-to-implement-continue-with-instagram-or-facebook-login-button-for-instagram  , plz?