# How to implement continue with Instagram or Facebook login button for Instagram basic display API?

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-login

I'm going to make login with Instagram to my website.

The website would control Instagram media with user's Instagram account. The website visitors are consumers.(i.e. non-business or non-creator)

So I should use Instagram basic display API (can't use Instagram graph API because that needs users to be a business or creator.)

I've tried to implement "login with Instagram", but the [developer guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/) says

> Instagram Graph API cannot access Instagram consumer accounts (i.e., non-Business or non-Creator Instagram accounts). If you are building an app for consumer users, use the Instagram Basic Display API instead.
>
> Instagram Basic Display is not an authentication solution. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead.

So I made "login with Facebook" button, but the problem is that if I log in with Facebook with Instagram scopes, that asks me to create Instagram business account while logging in. Oops. I returned to the first position.:(
What a loop? What's the solution? Did I understand the guide incorrectly?

Comment: What permissions are you asking for, precisely?

Comment: 'instagram_basic', 'pages_show_list'.
i asked these permissions.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started ?

Comment: yes, i followed that tutorial. so if i use facebook login button,shouldn't ask users to create business account?

Comment: So you are using testing this using an Instagram Test User you added to your app? You did accept the invitation? And you are logged in to IG with that account when you are testing this?

Comment: no, i don't use Test User.

Comment: how can i use instagram user credential to facebook login?

Comment: @CBroe, could you explain me flow of registering user with continue with facebook login button?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Instagram basic auth is indeed funky. If you want to use sdk, the users must have a business account that is associated with a Facebook Page and must login with Facebook username pass. But I also only want to connect Instagram to my app with instagram user-password and that doesnt work with Facebook sdk

Comment: how do you link facebook login to obtain user instagram linked account?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we use laravel socialite package replied on Upwork for the same.
https://socialiteproviders.com/Instagram/#installation-basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this approach

1. You ask their username (with message: if you enter your username then you agree our policy)
2. You can access their instagram data with this link [https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)
3. Login if username exist in your DB or Register if they are new user.

EDITED AFTER DISCUSSION IN COMMENT

No need to use library first you have to follow instruction from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

FYI I Use Laravel to create this simple app https://youtu.be/Qhg9vfB68J8?t=9

and my controller look like this

```
public function redirectToInstagramProvider()
{
    $appId       = "1564152940449991"; // change this to your appId
    $secret      = "f9711d1d48797fa30d4b2055ae5734f9"; // change this to your secret
    $redirectUri = "https://newgli.test/login/instagram/callback"; // change this to your redirectUri

    $redirectUri = urlencode($redirectUri);
    return redirect()->to("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?app_id={$appId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code");
}

public function instagramProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->code;
    if (empty($code)) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'Failed to login with Instagram.');
    }

    $appId       = "1564152940449991"; // change this to your appId
    $secret      = "f9711d1d48797fa30d4b2055ae5734f9"; // change this to your secret
    $redirectUri = "https://newgli.test/login/instagram/callback"; // change this to your redirectUri

    $client = new Client();

    // Get access token
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'app_id'       => $appId,
            'app_secret'   => $secret,
            'grant_type'   => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
            'code'         => $code,
        ],
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'Unauthorized login to Instagram.');
    }

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $content = json_decode($content);

    $accessToken = $content->access_token;
    $userId      = $content->user_id;

    // Get user info
    $response = $client->request('GET', "https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username,account_type&access_token={$accessToken}");

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $oAuth   = json_decode($content);
    dd($oAuth);
    // Get instagram user name
    $username = $oAuth->username;

    // do your code here
}
```

I know that code is not clean. You tweak the code to clean it. Maybe you can move your appId,Secret, redirectUrl to config file or .env file

Comment: for an example you can visit this url https://www.instagram.com/naufalluthfia/?__a=1

Comment: that is not third party auth solution.

Comment: Yes of course, because if you use Instagram Graph API will not allow basic account to publish media. maybe if you just need basic information you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

Comment: yes, i wanna use basic display api, but how can i implement user authentication?

Comment: Hi @thinkmore. i just create simple code. you can check in https://youtu.be/Qhg9vfB68J8. Just to make sure this is just like you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219827/discussion-between-dikutandi-and-thinkmore).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement exact same thing?? @thinkmore Have you implemented this?